# Sending and Recieving PNGencoded to php mysql BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to send encoded data for a bitmap image to a server and back to the( or a separate) client.  There's probably an easier way to do this with sockets or something, but I'm a very casual and still a pretty new programmer and I had trouble understanding other methods.  The encoding and decoding works fine and I can save and open up the encoded png, but somewhere on the php/mysql side the encoded data loses most of it's code.

Actionscript code for sending the encoded data to the php.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://host.net//img.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
var phpvar = new URLVariables();

var shape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
addChild(shape);
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 350);
bmp.draw(shape);

var byte:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bmp.encode(new Rectangle(0,0, 100, 100), new flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions(false), byte);

//save on database
phpvar.bytez = byte;
req.data = phpvar;
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(req);

trace(req.data.bytez);
```

The traced output is:

> PNG
>
> ->
>
> IHDRddÿIDATxÚíÐ1 µçYÁÏ"Ð)®F,Y²dɒ¥@,Y²dÉR
>   K,Y²d)%K,Y²Ȓ%K,Y dɒ%K,²dɒ%KY²dɒ%K,Y²dɒ¥@,Y²dÉR
>   K,Y²d)%K,Y²Ȓ%K,Y dɒ%K,²dɒ%KY²dɒ%K,Yß^Çjú··IEND®B`

Actionscript code for recieving data:

```
var req = new URLRequest("http://host.net//imgsend.php");
var loader = new URLLoader(req);


loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(req);



function onComplete(e:Event) {
    var loaderer:Loader = new Loader();
    var byte:ByteArray = new ByteArray()

    byte = e.target.data;
    trace(byte);
}
```

Traced output is:

> PNG
>
> ->

For some reason it knows the encoded data is for a PNG, but all there is is a header.  I think the problem is in my php/mysql code, but I'm not completely sure here.  I'm using a free webhosting service with phpMyAdmin for convenient sake, the Images table is just a BLOB column and the php files are uploaded on the host server.

PHP code for reading and inserting into mysql (img.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die(mysql_error());


$pic = $_POST['bytez'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO Images (img) VALUES ('$pic')";

mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

PHP code for taking the data form the server and sending it to Actionscript (imgsend.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die(mysql_error());




$sql = "SELECT * FROM Images";

$records = mysql_query($sql);

while($byte=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){

    echo $byte['img'];

}

?>
```

Comment: Just set a proper headers in PHP so that the output IS image, and then use `Loader` inside ActionScript in order to load image. This way you won't do the encoding/decoding by yourself, it will be automatic.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: even encoded what you send to the server is a string so save it as string (TEXT on sqlite)

Comment: I know a little of that Marc B, thanks!  This isn't for any final product yet, mostly testing.  If I do end up turning this into a public project I will definitely look more into that.  I'm still lost for storing the image as an image inside mysql, but I'll try messing with TEXT fields on sql.

Comment: Web isn't my strong suite, but I believe you store the image on the file system, and the *URL* of the image in MySQL. I don't think you're supposed to be able to store the image itself in SQL. So you have the database return the URL, and have Flash download the image from the URL with another Loader.

Comment: I was reading into that some, user45623, but I'm having trouble understanding how the file goes from AS3 to PHP, let alone from PHP to the file system.  I know how to save the file on the disk, but the C drive is not a valid URL to have an AS3 client download it.  BTW, the final concept isn't going to be web, it will be AIR.

Comment: Your method of sending the file to the server seems fine to me; you just need to find out how to have PHP save the file instead of writing the raw bytes into your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't necessarily find an answer to this exact method, but I found an alternate solution, ie writing the file directly into the directory.  From what I've read this is much more efficient anyways.  The code is basically the same only I added URLcontentType and extended the URL for the URL request address for the file's location.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://host.net//img.php?filename=something.png");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.contentType = "application/octet-stream";

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;


var shape:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
addChild(shape);
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 350);
bmp.draw(shape);

var byte:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bmp.encode(new Rectangle(0,0, 100, 100), new flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions(false), byte);

//save on database
req.data = byte;
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(req);
```

The PHP code is for img.php is:

```
<?php

   $fileName = $_GET['filename'];

   $fp = fopen( $fileName, 'wb' );

   fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] );    

   fclose( $fp );

?>
```

Loading the file is simple, not going to bother posting that.  I'll deal with unique file names on my own, baby steps.  Thanks for helping me talk this out some!